# Numerical solving of Maxwell equations for multiple frequencies: FDTD vs FEM

Tags: electromagnetism, computational-physics

For thesis I need to compare FDTD (used in the study) vs FEM. In case of FDTD I can use a Gaussian pulse to model multiple frequencies at the same time.

Does FEM require running the simulation for each frequency in case of linear materials? Are there any papers about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you mean exactly by FEM. Often times, FEM refers to a frequency-domain method, so it will only solve the fields at a particular frequency. If you want the fields at multiple frequencies, you would need to run a simulation separately for each frequency. This is one of the big disadvantages of using frequency-domain methods compared to time-domain methods like FDTD. That said, there are [time-domain variants of FEM](https://cecas.clemson.edu/cvel/modeling/tutorials/techniques/fetd/fetd.html).